# keys for which value lies between lower and upper bin columns pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe `df1` in which there are four columns:

```
key, lower_limit_A1, upper_limit_A1, lower_limit_A2, upper_limit_A2
1, 10, 20, 90, 100
2, 10, 20, 100, 110
3, 20, 30, 110, 120
4, 20, 30, 120, 130
5, 30, 40, 130, 140
6, 30, 40, 140, 150
```

I have another dataframe `df2` in which actual values of `A1`  is there

```
key_value, A1, A2
K1, 15, 105
K2, 35, 145
K3, 25, 115
```

I am trying to associate keys to the key value on basis of defined upper limit and lower limit for combination of A1 and A2 variables :

```
key_value, key
K1, 2
K2, 6
K3, 3
```

So far, I am not sure how to proceed on this but was trying to do with antijoin :

```
df1.join(
    df2, 
    [df1.lower_limit_A1 <= df2.A1, df1.upper_limit_A1 >= df2.wind_speed], 
    how='left_anti'
)
```

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An inner join should be appropriate here. You can specify the conditions for the values A1 and A2 to be between the limits.

```
results = df2.join(
    df1,
    df2.A1.between(df1.lower_limit_A1, df1.upper_limit_A1) &
    df2.A2.between(df1.lower_limit_A2, df1.upper_limit_A2)
).select('key_value', 'key')
```